# Yii2 ActiveForm fields options does not work

Tags: php, yii2

According to the [official tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-forms.html#creating-views) of Yii2. I have created a view for the entry form:

```
    <?php
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
    ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<!-- GET Attention for the next Line -->
    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->label('Your Name'); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'email'); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <?=  Html::submitButton('Send!', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']); ?>
    </div>    
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

At this point everything is well fine. However, when I try to use the parameter `options` of the `field` method as follows:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name', ['style' => 'color:red'])->label('Your Name'); ?>
```

I have got the error:

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
>
> Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\ActiveField::style

[The official api documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#field()-detail) stated that method of ActiveForm takes a third parameter called options

Could anybody explain me why this error has been occurred?!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['style' => 'color:red'])->label('Your Name'); ?>
```

It is a little hard to explain, when you do `$form->field($model, 'name')` without specifying the field type you are actually asking for a textInput. But that does not mean that you should ask from `->field(` to take the params the same way as `->textInput(` does. If you need to put some special params for the field you have to use the explicit `->textInput(['style' => 'color:red'])`

Comment: The official Documentation talks about a third parameter "options". But it doesn't explain what could be defined using it. :(

Comment: You are right, that should be better documented. I may add some things in there next week.

Answer (score 9):

Try this code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name', [ 'options' => [ 'style' => 'color: red']])->label('Your Name'); ?>
```

You've got this error

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\ActiveField::style
```

because there is no such property style. You should use 'options' and pass 'style' as sub-array

Comment: This is corect answer!

Answer (score 1):

This way is for especify options on all the "field" (that includes the "label" and the "input") but 'style'=>'color:red' only affects to label in this way, I use this for especify class options instead of color:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name', [ 'options' => [ 'class' => 'col-xs-8']])->label('Your Name'); ?>
```

If you want to especify options for one of them (label or input)you can do it separately, like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['style' => 'color:red'])->label('Your Name',['style'=>'color:blue']); ?>
```

Yii is so flexible, that is what i like of it.